# Can python asyncore module handle/connect more than one socket?

Tags: python, sockets, asyncore

I have a class that implements the asyncore module, it serves as a client that connects to HOST_A. The problem is I need to pass the data received from HOST_A to a HOST_B. So i'm wondering if asyncore can create two socket connections to HOST_A and HOST_B.Is this possible?

Comment: What makes you doubt that it could? Have you tried this out yet? You should be able to create another dispatcher, no problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  When asking questions, it'd be good if you could provide details of a possible reasoning as to why _you_ believe it may or may not work, what you have tried to attempt to prove that it's the case and your specific use case (if any).  This helps answerers to tell how best to approach your question, and provide the best appropriate perspective accordingly.  You might want to know more on [what Stack Overflow is about](http://stackoverflow.com/about) to help yourself understand how Stack Overflow works.  Thanks!

Comment: I have tried calling another dispatcher within the constructor of my working dispatcher that connects to host A. The problem is suddenly the dispatcher for host A is unable to connect to host A.

Comment: Please read [this advice on asking good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (I recommend following the link at the bottom to Jon Skeet's blog post [Writing the perfect question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx), and paying particular attention to the "Golden Rule").

Answer (score 0):

You can make one connection per socket at the same time only. But this doesn't mean that you can't do what you want to, however you'll need 2 sockets for 2 connections.